# Como Editar El Front En En Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

Estoy Haciendo Una Pagina Usando Laravel 6 y Esta Casi Termianda Pero Nescesito Editar La Parte Del Front End, Pero Al Momento De Inspecionar La Pagina Me Encontre Este Archivo Llamado "Index", Al Buscarlo En Las Carpetas No Se Encuentra Por Ningun Lado, Realice Mi Busqueda Por La Documentacion y Por Internet Pero No Encontre Nada y Por Eso Es Que Acudo Aqui. 
Espero y Alguien Pueda Resolrveme Esta Duda, Gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las vistas las puedes encontrar en `resources/views` ahi deberían estar los archivos necesarios

Comment: Estuve Buscando Ahi, Pero Al Momento De Abrir Los Archivos No Se Encuentra Ninguno Donde Pueda Editar Esa Parte, Solo Se Hace Referencia a @extends('layouts.app') Pero El Archivo app No Es El Archivo Que Estoy Buscando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

las vistas las puedes encontrar en **resources/views**.
Si lo que quieres es acceder al código de login y register, probablemente veas que tu home hace referencia a **@extends('layouts.app')**.

- para acceder a layouts.app, debes ir a **resources/views/layouts**, encontrarás un archivo llamado **app.blade.php**, desde el puedes modificar el Front-end de tu vista home principal.

Foto para ilustrar la carpeta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En ese archivo encontraras el siguiente código, mismo que muestras en la imagen.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- CSRF Token -->
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

  <!-- Fonts -->
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Styles -->
  <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div id="app">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                </ul>
                <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    @guest
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                        </li>
                        @if (Route::has('register'))
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                            </li>
                        @endif
                    @else
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>

                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                   onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                 document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                    {{ __('Logout') }}
                                </a>
                                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                    @csrf
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    @endguest
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <main class="py-4">
        @yield('content')
    </main>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Desde este archivo puedes modificar lo que creo que estas buscando.
Espero y sea de ayuda la respuesta.

Comment: Deberías considero checar lo que el OP respondió a mi comentario que le dejé donde también le mencioné sobre dicha ubicación; considera esperar a que la pregunta esté mejor planteada ya que de lo contrario solo nos estamos basando en suposiciones

Comment: suposiciones no amigo, si notas bien ese archivo es el mismo del pantallazo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, Creo Que Ya Vi Lo Que Estaba Haciendo Mal
Saludos.

Comment: Con mucho gusto :)